# Getting Right click on Waveshare touchscreen

Tags: touchscreen, mouse

I have fitted this [Waveshare 10 inch LCD touchscreen](https://thepihut.com/products/hdmi-10-1-1280x800-touch-screen-and-case) to my Pi4B (buster).  It all works fine but I can't find a way to achieve a Right Mouse Click. Is there a way to get a right click?

Comment: how do you do a right mouse click on a smartphone?

Answer (score 2):

If long press does not work you can try

```
sudo nano /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Paste in:

```
Section "InputClass"
   Identifier "calibration"
   Driver "evdev"
   MatchProduct "FT5406 memory based driver"

   Option "EmulateThirdButton" "1"
   Option "EmulateThirdButtonTimeout" "750"
   Option "EmulateThirdButtonMoveThreshold" "30"
EndSection
```

Save the file and reboot (yes reboot is needed).

Taken from [here](https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/hardware/display/troubleshooting.md)

Comment: That didn't work for me. I think your link refers to the Official Pi Touchscreen. The file xorg.conf didn't exist so I created it. Was that correct?

Comment: The above snippet needs to be edited to reflect the name of the actual device:
Change `MatchProduct "…"` to match the name of the device, such as returned by `xinput`
Assuming your Waveshare is [this one](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/10.1inch_HDMI_LCD_(H)_(with_case)), the identifier  is `waveshare HDMI/VGA/AV RTD2660H Viedo Board` [sic]

Comment: Also, rather than `xorg.conf`, you may want to create a `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/99-waveshare-.conf`file… (but either should work)